# Single Inheritance Empty Base Optimization Not Working on MSVC

Tags: c++, inheritance, composition, single-inheritance

Why is the following not working?

If `sizeof(B)` is 8, so `sizeof(C)` should also be 8 since it's inheriting from a single classe, EBO should've been still be used here.

Do I really have to use `__declspec(empty_bases)` here? :/

```
struct A {};

struct B : A {
    size_t x;
};

struct C : A {
    B b;
};

int
main() {

    static_assert(sizeof(C) == sizeof(size_t));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you intend to compare sizeof(C) == sizeof(B)?

Comment: Yes, that's the intentation

Comment: This doesn't work in g++ either: [**Live demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dea3bb2df5cb8f2f)

Comment: but that still doesnt tell you if empty base class optimization was applied. You would have to compare `sizeof(C)` to `sizeof` a `struct D { B b; }`, but I think even that cannot tell you reliably if ebo was applied or not

Comment: "If sizeof(B) is 8, so sizeof(C) should also be 8 " you make the assumption that `sizeof(C)` is size of members + size of base class, but also without the base class `sizeof(C)` is not necessary `sizeof(B)`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Yes: [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10a4c673117b5e07): `8 vs. 16`

Comment: If I got it right, OPs case is similar like the `struct Derived2` in the (counter) example of [Empty base optimization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo) (but it all made me dizzy a bit).

Comment: Does anyone has any idea on how to shrink the size of the struct to its most absolute aligned minimum?

Comment: It looks like you get what you expect if C is derived from a different empty class. Possibly this is so that two different members of the same type do not share an address.